# eigenvectors complex nonsymmetric matrix in R different from Matlab: how to solve the this?

Tags: r, matlab, matrix, complex-numbers, eigenvector

I want to compute the eigenvalues of a complex matrix in R. 
Comparing the values obtained in MATLAB, I don't get the same eigenvalues obtained in R computing it from the exact same matrix.

In R, I used `eigen()`. In MATLAB used `eig()` or `eigs()` (both functions give out the same eigenvalues but different to the R ones).

For real matrices, R and MATLAB are consistent. 
How to get in R the same result of MATLAB ?

Example in Matlab **real matrix**:

```
squeeze(Sigma_X(:,:,h+1)) %real matrix 10x10
ans =

1.0e+03 *

Columns 1 through 6

5.8706    5.9966    6.1225    6.2484    6.3744    6.5003
5.9966    6.1260    6.2554    6.3849    6.5143    6.6438
6.1225    6.2554    6.3884    6.5213    6.6543    6.7872
6.2484    6.3849    6.5213    6.6578    6.7942    6.9306
6.3744    6.5143    6.6543    6.7942    6.9341    7.0741
6.5003    6.6438    6.7872    6.9306    7.0741    7.2175
6.6263    6.7732    6.9201    7.0671    7.2140    7.3609
6.7522    6.9026    7.0531    7.2035    7.3539    7.5044
6.8782    7.0321    7.1860    7.3399    7.4939    7.6478
7.0041    7.1615    7.3190    7.4764    7.6338    7.7912

Columns 7 through 10

6.6263    6.7522    6.8782    7.0041
6.7732    6.9026    7.0321    7.1615
6.9201    7.0531    7.1860    7.3190
7.0671    7.2035    7.3399    7.4764
7.2140    7.3539    7.4939    7.6338
7.3609    7.5044    7.6478    7.7912
7.5079    7.6548    7.8017    7.9487
7.6548    7.8052    7.9557    8.1061
7.8017    7.9557    8.1096    8.2635
7.9487    8.1061    8.2635    8.4210

opt.disp = 0;
[P, D] = eigs(squeeze(Sigma_X(:,:,h+1)),q,'LM',opt) %compute the eigenvalues and eigenvectors

 P =

-0.2872    0.5128
-0.2936    0.4029
-0.2999    0.2930
-0.3062    0.1830
-0.3125    0.0731
-0.3189   -0.0368
-0.3252   -0.1467
-0.3315   -0.2566
-0.3379   -0.3665
-0.3442   -0.4764

D =

1.0e+04 *

7.0984         0
     0    0.0054
```

Example in R **real matrix**:

```
drop(Sigma_X[,,h+1]) #Same real matrix as before, 10x10

Columns 1 through 5

 5870.610+0i 5996.552+0i 6122.495+0i 6248.438+0i 6374.381+0i 
 5996.552+0i 6125.994+0i 6255.435+0i 6384.876+0i 6514.317+0i 
 6122.495+0i 6255.435+0i 6388.375+0i 6521.314+0i 6654.254+0i 
 6248.438+0i 6384.876+0i 6521.314+0i 6657.752+0i 6794.190+0i 
 6374.381+0i 6514.317+0i 6654.254+0i 6794.190+0i 6934.127+0i 
 6500.324+0i 6643.759+0i 6787.194+0i 6930.629+0i 7074.063+0i 
 6626.267+0i 6773.200+0i 6920.133+0i 7067.067+0i 7214.000+0i 
 6752.210+0i 6902.641+0i 7053.073+0i 7203.505+0i 7353.937+0i 
 6878.152+0i 7032.083+0i 7186.013+0i 7339.943+0i 7493.873+0i 
 7004.095+0i 7161.524+0i 7318.952+0i 7476.381+0i 7633.810+0i 

 Columns 6 through 10

 6500.324+0i 6626.267+0i 6752.210+0i 6878.152+0i 7004.095+0i
 6643.759+0i 6773.200+0i 6902.641+0i 7032.083+0i 7161.524+0i
 6787.194+0i 6920.133+0i 7053.073+0i 7186.013+0i 7318.952+0i
 6930.629+0i 7067.067+0i 7203.505+0i 7339.943+0i 7476.381+0i
 7074.063+0i 7214.000+0i 7353.937+0i 7493.873+0i 7633.810+0i
 7217.498+0i 7360.933+0i 7504.368+0i 7647.803+0i 7791.238+0i
 7360.933+0i 7507.867+0i 7654.800+0i 7801.733+0i 7948.667+0i
 7504.368+0i 7654.800+0i 7805.232+0i 7955.663+0i 8106.095+0i
 7647.803+0i 7801.733+0i 7955.663+0i 8109.594+0i 8263.524+0i
 7791.238+0i 7948.667+0i 8106.095+0i 8263.524+0i 8420.952+0i

 Decomp <- eigen(drop(Sigma_X[,,h+1])) #frequency 0
 DD <- diag(Decomp$values[1:q])
 PP <- Decomp$vectors[,1:q] 

 PP

 [1,] -0.2872322+0i  0.5127886+0i
 [2,] -0.2935595+0i  0.4028742+0i
 [3,] -0.2998868+0i  0.2929598+0i
 [4,] -0.3062141+0i  0.1830454+0i
 [5,] -0.3125415+0i  0.0731310+0i
 [6,] -0.3188688+0i -0.0367834+0i
 [7,] -0.3251961+0i -0.1466978+0i
 [8,] -0.3315234+0i -0.2566122+0i
 [9,] -0.3378507+0i -0.3665266+0i
[10,] -0.3441780+0i -0.4764410+0i

 DD

 [1,] 70983.65  0.00000
 [2,]     0.00 54.34878
```

AS YOU CAN SEE, WHEN THE MATRIX IS REAL, MATLAB AND R GIVE YOU BACK THE SAME EIGENVECTORS AND EIGENVALUES.

LET'S TRY THE SAME CODE BUT WITH A COMPLEX MATRIX.

Example in Matlab **complex matrix**:

```
j=1

squeeze(Sigma_X(:,:,j))

ans =

1.0e+02 *

Columns 1 through 5

3.4601+0.0000i 3.5075-0.0304i 3.5548-0.0607i 3.6022-0.0911i 3.6496-0.1215i
3.5075+0.0304i 3.5562+0.0000i 3.6049-0.0304i 3.6535-0.0607i 3.7022-0.0911i
3.5548+0.0607i 3.6049+0.0304i 3.6549+0.0000i 3.7049-0.0304i 3.7549- 0.0607i
3.6022+0.0911i 3.6535+0.0607i 3.7049+0.0304i 3.7562+0.0000i 3.8075- 0.0304i
3.6496+0.1215i 3.7022+0.0911i 3.7549+0.0607i 3.8075+0.0304i 3.8602+ 0.0000i
3.6970+0.1518i 3.7509+0.1215i 3.8049+0.0911i 3.8588+0.0607i 3.9128+ 0.0304i
3.7444+0.1822i 3.7996+0.1518i 3.8549+0.1215i 3.9102+0.0911i 3.9654+ 0.0607i
3.7917+0.2126i  3.8483+0.1822i 3.9049+0.1518i 3.9615+0.1215i 4.0181+ 0.0911i
3.8391+0.2429i 3.8970+0.2126i 3.9549+0.1822i 4.0128+0.1518i 4.0707+ 0.1215i
3.8865+0.2733i 3.9457+0.2429i 4.0049+0.2126i 4.0641+0.1822i 4.1234+ 0.1518i

Columns 6 through 10

3.6970-0.1518i 3.7444-0.1822i 3.7917-0.2126i 3.8391-0.2429i 3.8865- 0.2733i
3.7509-0.1215i 3.7996-0.1518i 3.8483-0.1822i 3.8970-0.2126i 3.9457- 0.2429i
3.8049-0.0911i 3.8549-0.1215i 3.9049-0.1518i 3.9549-0.1822i 4.0049- 0.2126i
3.8588-0.0607i 3.9102-0.0911i 3.9615-0.1215i 4.0128-0.1518i 4.0641- 0.1822i
3.9128-0.0304i 3.9654-0.0607i 4.0181-0.0911i 4.0707-0.1215i 4.1234- 0.1518i
3.9668+0.0000i 4.0207-0.0304i 4.0747-0.0607i 4.1286-0.0911i 4.1826- 0.1215i
4.0207+0.0304i 4.0760+0.0000i 4.1313-0.0304i 4.1865-0.0607i 4.2418- 0.0911i
4.0747+0.0607i 4.1313+0.0304i 4.1878+0.0000i 4.2444-0.0304i 4.3010- 0.0607i
4.1286+0.0911i 4.1865+0.0607i 4.2444+0.0304i 4.3023+0.0000i 4.3602- 0.0304i
4.1826+0.1215i 4.2418+0.0911i 4.3010+0.0607i 4.3602+0.0304i 4.4195+ 0.0000i

[P, D] = eigs(squeeze(Sigma_X(:,:,j)),q,'LM',opt);


P =

 -0.1206 - 0.2711i     0.0471 + 0.5052i
 -0.1199 - 0.2760i     0.0384 + 0.3955i
 -0.1192 - 0.2810i     0.0297 + 0.2859i
 -0.1186 - 0.2859i     0.0210 + 0.1762i
 -0.1179 - 0.2908i     0.0124 + 0.0666i
 -0.1172 - 0.2957i     0.0037 - 0.0430i
 -0.1165 - 0.3006i    -0.0050 - 0.1527i
 -0.1159 - 0.3055i    -0.0137 - 0.2623i
 -0.1152 - 0.3104i    -0.0224 - 0.3720i
 -0.1145 - 0.3153i    -0.0311 - 0.4816i
D =

  1.0e+03 *

  3.9211 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i
  0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0029 - 0.0000i
```

Example in R **complex matrix**:

```
j=1
drop(Sigma_X[,,j])

Columns 1 through 4

346.0094+0.0000i  350.7470-3.0368i  355.4846-6.0736i  360.2222-9.1104i 
350.7470+3.0368i  355.6162+0.0000i  360.4854-3.0368i  365.3546-6.0736i 
355.4846+6.0736i  360.4854+3.0368i  365.4862+0.0000i  370.4870-3.0368i 
360.2222+9.1104i  365.3546+6.0736i  370.4870+3.0368i  375.6194+0.0000i 
364.9598+12.1472i 370.2238+9.1104i  375.4878+6.0736i  380.7518+3.0368i 
369.6974+15.1839i 375.0930+12.1472i 380.4886+9.1104i  385.8842+6.0736i 
374.4350+18.2207i 379.9622+15.1839i 385.4894+12.1472i 391.0166+9.1104i 
379.1726+21.2575i 384.8314+18.2207i 390.4902+15.1839i 396.1490+12.1472i 
383.9102+24.2943i 389.7006+21.2575i 395.4910+18.2207i 401.2814+15.1839i 
388.6478+27.3311i 394.5698+24.2943i 400.4918+21.2575i 406.4138+18.2207i 

Columns 5 through 7

 364.9598-12.1472i 369.6974-15.1839i 374.4350-18.2207i
 370.2238-9.1104i  375.0930-12.1472i 379.9622-15.1839i
 375.4878-6.0736i  380.4886-9.1104i  385.4894-12.1472i
 380.7518-3.0368i  385.8842-6.0736i  391.0166-9.1104i
 386.0158+ 0.0000i 391.2798- 3.0368i 396.5438- 6.0736i 
 391.2798+ 3.0368i 396.6754+ 0.0000i 402.0710- 3.0368i
 396.5438+ 6.0736i 402.0710+ 3.0368i 407.5982+ 0.0000i         
 401.8078+ 9.1104i 407.4666+ 6.0736i 413.1254+ 3.0368i
 407.0718+12.1472i 412.8622+ 9.1104i 418.6526+ 6.0736i
 412.3358+15.1839i 418.2578+12.1472i 424.1798+ 9.1104i

Columns 8 through 10

  379.1726-21.2575i 383.9102-24.2943i 388.6478-27.3311i
  384.8314-18.2207i 389.7006-21.2575i 394.5698-24.2943i
  390.4902-15.1839i 395.4910-18.2207i 400.4918-21.2575i
  396.1490-12.1472i 401.2814-15.1839i 406.4138-18.2207i
  401.8078- 9.1104i 407.0718-12.1472i 412.3358-15.1839i
  407.4666- 6.0736i 412.8622- 9.1104i 418.2578-12.1472i
  413.1254- 3.0368i 418.6526- 6.0736i 424.1798- 9.1104i
  418.7842+ 0.0000i 424.4430- 3.0368i 430.1018- 6.0736i
  424.4430+ 3.0368i 430.2334+ 0.0000i 436.0237- 3.0368i
  430.1018+ 6.0736i 436.0237+ 3.0368i 441.9457+ 0.0000i
```

As you can see, the matrix is the same as those computed before in Matlab.
Let's compute eigenvalues and eigenvectors.

```
PP

[1,] -0.2967359+0.0000000i  0.50734838+0.00000000i
[2,] -0.3009476-0.0026119i  0.39737421-0.00152766i
[3,] -0.3051593-0.0052239i  0.28740004-0.00305533i
[4,] -0.3093709-0.0078358i  0.17742587-0.00458299i
[5,] -0.3135826-0.0104478i  0.06745170-0.00611065i
[6,] -0.3177943-0.0130597i -0.04252247-0.00763831i
[7,] -0.3220060-0.0156717i -0.15249664-0.00916598i
[8,] -0.3262177-0.0182836i -0.26247080-0.01069364i
[9,] -0.3304294-0.0208955i -0.37244497-0.01222130i
[10,] -0.3346411-0.0235075i -0.48241914-0.01374896i


DD

 3921.066 0.000000
    0.000 2.917833
```

As you can see, the eigenvalues are the same as those computed with MATLAB, but the eigenvectors are different.  How can I get the same eigenvectors as those of MATLAB?

Comment: Check who is right, look here:
[https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/894636/verifying-eigenvalues](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/894636/verifying-eigenvalues)

Comment: You should at least post the matrix you tested, and the results you got

Comment: @chtz here i provided the example. can you please help me to solve the problem now?

Comment: @chtz here i provided the example, can you help me?

Comment: Eigenvectors are not unique, since scaling an eigenvector by any scalar is still an eigenvector. In the complex case, this means, multiplying by any unit-number still gives a unit-eigenvector. How is it relevant in your case, to get exactly the same Eigenvectors?

Comment: @chtz yes, it is really important because i have to write in r the same algorithm that i have in matlab, and as you can see above the two results are different (same eigenvalues but different eigenvectors). with different eigenvectors the result of the algo is going to be really different.

Comment: @chtz if you can help me i will be thankful forever because i'm struggling and i have to consign this next friday.

Comment: It really shouldn't matter, if you work with an Eigenvector of `[1+0i; 0+1i]` or `[0+1i, -1+0i]` (simplified example). If it really does matter, maybe open a question about the algorithm you are using.

Comment: luca, the point of @chtz is that the eigenvectors are defined up to at least a scalar factor's freedom (and this can be a _complex_ scalar too!), and in case of degenerate eigenvalues there's even larger freedom with choosing eigenvectors. Ideally whatever you do with the eigenvectors should not be sensitive to this choice at all in the end result. If your code breaks symmetry somehow, this might not be the case. See also the duplicate I'm going to suggest in a second. Having an attitude when others are trying to help you is anything but helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is simple but difficult to see because the vectors are complex. 
If you enter both your matrices in MATLAB, and do this

```
 P(:,1)./PP(:,1)

 ans =
0.4064 + 0.9136i
0.4063 + 0.9136i
0.4063 + 0.9139i
0.4065 + 0.9138i
0.4064 + 0.9138i
0.4063 + 0.9138i
0.4063 + 0.9138i
0.4065 + 0.9137i
0.4064 + 0.9137i
0.4063 + 0.9137i
```

you see that they are linearly dependent, same for the other one.

I am afraid, that there is no way that I know of, that guarantees you the same result within both programs. Computing eigenvalues and vectors in general is not easy, and slight differences in implementation result in the differences that you see.

To get the same result you could try normalizing the vectors with their first component, meaning

```
P(:,1)/P(1,1)   and  PP(:,1)/PP(1,1)
```

That gives me the same vectors, modulo small differences, as you provide a different number of digits for your examples.

Edit: Another test shows, that this is indeed what Matlab does, in addition to normalizing the length to 1. So

```
tmp=P(:,1)/P(1,1);
tmp/norm(tmp)
```

returns the same vector as your Matlab Example.

Comment: can you explain to me the second test?

Comment: The second bit of code is no test, but something you can do in R to get the same results as in Matlab. Unfortunately I don't know R, so I can't suggest the equivalent expression. 
Also, what I showed was, that they are the same. As mentioned in one of the comments of your question, eigenvectors are not unique. R gives you something of norm 1, Matlab gives you something of norm 1 with a real first component.

Comment: @lucadibo crown42's point is that there's a global complex factor difference between the two sets of eigenvectors. If `v` is an eigenvector from one code, then the corresponding eigenvector from the other code is `c*v` for a specific complex number `c`. Both are right! If your matrix is `A`, `A*(c*v)=c*(A*v)`, so both `v` and `c*v` are valid eigenvectors of `A` with the same eigenvalue. The _mathematical problem is not defined_. If your code relies on the specific choice of eigenvectors, it's possibly wrong and anyway you have to handle this yourself, perhaps by figuring out `c`.

Comment: To be fair, in some contexts (e.g. Koopman-Operator) one takes a specific eigenvector to be an approximation of an probability density, in which case there is a unique correct eigenvector, the normalized one.
I have no idea what lucadibo intents, but it is feasible that he has extra conditions.

Comment: Yeah, I can also think of situations where results depend on the specific vectors, but "physical" end results should be invariant. In any case, OP has to understand that there have to be additional constraints on the eigenvectors, otherwise both sets are "correct".

Comment: Of course, dividing by `P(1,1)` can be dangerous, if that value happens to be (close to) zero. And as we've all been trying to explain to the OP, this should really not be necessary!